# Question about a solution to a problem involving $x^2\lt a$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

If $a \gt 0$ show that the solution set of the inequality $x^2 \lt a$ consists of all numbers $x$ for which $-\sqrt a \lt x \lt \sqrt a$.
Solution:
$$x^2 \lt a \Longrightarrow$$
$$x^2 - a \lt 0\Longrightarrow$$
$$(x + \sqrt a)(x - \sqrt a) \lt 0$$

If $x \lt -\sqrt a$ then $x + \sqrt a \lt 0$ and $x -\sqrt a \lt -2\sqrt a \lt 0$ therefore $(x + \sqrt a)(x - \sqrt a) \gt 0$ which is a contradiction.
There is more to the solution but my question is why is $-2\sqrt a$ used? Is the solution valid with just $x -\sqrt a \lt 0$ instead of $x -\sqrt a \lt -2\sqrt a \lt 0$? It would seem to yield the same contradiction.
Thanks

Comment: $<0=$ is not a good notation.

Comment: @DietrichBurde what should be used?

Comment: Better is $\Longrightarrow$ or $\Longleftrightarrow$.

Answer (score 1):

There is $-2\sqrt{a}$ because $x>-\sqrt{a}$ (the assumption) and $x$ is estimated upward to $-\sqrt{a}$. The upwards estimated difference is hence $-2\sqrt{a}$. Both are practically the same, $-2\sqrt{a}$ is one reasoning step.